# Why is the term 'reduce' used in the context of NP complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, computation-theory, np

Why is the term 'reduce' used when B is at least as hard?

In the context of NP complexity, we say that A is reducible to B in polynomial time, namely, `A ≤ B` where A is a known hard problem and we try to show that it can be reduced to B, a problem with unknown hardness.

Suppose we prove it successfully, that means that B is *at least as hard* as A. Then what exactly is reduced? It does not seem to be inline with the meaning of 'reduce' when B is a problem that is harder and less general.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce comes from the latin "reducere", composed of "re" (back) and "ducere" (to lead). In this context, it literally means "bring back, convert", since the problem of deciding if an element x is in A is converted to the problem of deciding if a suitably transformed input f(x) is in B.

Let me observe that the notion of reducibility is used in may different context apart from (NP) complexity. In particular, it originated in computability theory.